# Unable to Hide Vertical Scroll Bar on Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am displaying an HTML page within another HTML page depending on which link is selected using the following function:

```
function loadProject(sel) {
    var url = sel[sel.selectedIndex].value;

    if(url) {
        document.getElementById('projectContainer').innerHTML = '<' + 'object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+url+'"><\/object>';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('projectContainer').innerHTML = "Please select a project.";
    }
}
```

And, I have a div tag inside the HTML with the id of projectContainer.  This works, except for the fact that a vertical scroll bar is **always** shown no matter what I do to remove it.  (It shouldn't be - even if I put nothing into the object, the vertical bar is still shown.)  I have tried to edit the CSS in the following:

```
object {
    width: 100%; 
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

but that is not accomplishing what I'm looking for.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: What browser are we talking about? And where exactly is the scroll bar? Isn't there an iframe involved when you talk about a "page inside a page"?

Comment: @Pekka - I'm going for a cross-browser approach if possible (testing in Chrome and IE).  As for the IFrame, it is not needed when doing it using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `<object>` is new to me but very similar to an iframe, I suppose: It means that there is a document body that is separate from the surrounding document.

You need to declare `overflow: hidden` for the `body` *inside* the document you are embedding.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` won't work for content inside an iframe/frame/object. You are going to need to edit the CSS of the pages being rendered in the object tag. Also, I recommend you **DO NOT do this**, as you don't know if I have my browser set by default to have forced huge text due to bad sight or something similar, which would make the scrollbar unusable/hidden to me, hindering usability. Just don't do what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's a bit harsh. We don't know that this page will even be publicly viewable.

Answer (score 0):

make it overflow: auto; it works!