# Increasing the Size of Object Frame to Remove Scroll Bars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I [recently asked how to hide the vertical scroll bar using overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942446/unable-to-hide-vertical-scroll-bar-on-web-page).  While the answer did work (the scroll bar is hidden), I am wondering why it's even appearing in the first place.  I would think that including an object inside another page would automatically grow to the size that is needed unless otherwise constrained (which, I don't believe I'm doing).  The CSS for my object is:

```
object {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Any suggestions to allowing the entire object to be the full size it needs to be, instead of hiding it?  Thank you.

P.S.  For the record, the entire site is run off a local machine - it won't have any network access.

**Edit:** [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655/making-an-iframe-take-vertical-space) is almost exactly what I'm looking to do, but with an object rather than an iFrmae.  However, I can't seem to get this to resize the containing div to the correct size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html, body, object {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
}
```

The `<object>` will be 100% size of the window with this CSS. `<html>` *and* `<body>` must be included as to set `<html>`s height to 100%.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.  The frame (object) that's inside goes off the bottom of the page, but no scroll bar appears on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset all margins and padding to 0, so that no 'hidden' space is taken up